# unable to update dictionary keys python

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe, panel

I am trying to update the values in a dict as follows:

```
method_list=[1,2,3]
sym_list=['a','b','c']
new_DF= pd.DataFrame([56,34,12],columns=["x"])

panel_methods=pd.Panel(dict.fromkeys(method_list))
s=dict.fromkeys(sym_list,panel_methods) 
for isym, sym in enumerate(sym_list):
    for im, m in enumerate(method_list):
         s[sym][m]= new_DF
```

Although get_new_DF() outputs a dataframe, the value of s[sym][m] remains empty. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: can you give us some example data that you are using. It is a little hard to follow what you're doing without it.

Comment: pls see the sample values above